# Show that $f\big(\text{Ker}(g)\big)\subseteq \text{Ker}(g)$ and $f\big(\text{Im}(g)\big)\subseteq \text{Im}(g)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, definition

> Let $f, g:V\to V$ be linear maps on a vector spce $V$ such that $f\big(g(v)\big)=g\big(f(v)\big)$ for all $v\in V$.
>
> 1) Is is true that $f\big(\text{Ker}(g)\big)\subseteq \text{Ker}(g)$?
>
> 2) Is it true that $f\big(\text{Im}(g)\big)\subseteq \text{Im}(g)$?

What does it mean $f\big(\text{Ker}(g)\big)$? Does it mean the image of $\text{Ker}(g)$? I have no idea how to start these kind of questions....

Comment: $f(\mathrm{Ker}(g))$ is the image of $\mathrm{Ker}(g)$ under $f$, or if you prefer
$ f(\mathrm{Ker}(g)) = \left\{ f(z) : z \in \mathrm{Ker}(g) \right\}. $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $f$ and $g$ are linear maps.  The meanings of $f(\ker g)$ and $f(\operatorname{im} g)$ are, respectively, the image of $\ker g$ and the image of $\operatorname{im} g$ under $f$, i.e.,
$$f(\ker g)=\big\{f(x):x\in \ker g\big\}$$
and
$$f(\operatorname{im} g)=\big\{f(y):y\in \operatorname{im} g\big\}.$$

> (1)  Let $x\in \ker g$.  Then, $$g\big(f(x)\big)=f\big(g(x)\big)=f(0)=0,$$ so $f(x)\in \ker g$.  This proves that $f(\ker g)\subseteq \ker g$. 
>  More generally, if $V_\lambda(g)$ is the eigenspace of $g$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $f\big(V_\lambda(g)\big)\subseteq V_\lambda(g)$.  Note that $\ker g= V_0(g)$.  (We also have $f\big(V^\lambda(g)\big)\subseteq V^\lambda(g)$ if $V^\lambda(g)$ is the generalized eigenspace of $g$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.)  
>  
> (2)  Let $y\in \operatorname{im}g$.  Then, $y=g(x)$ for some $x\in V$.  Therefore, $$f(y)=f\big(g(x)\big)=g\big(f(x)\big)\in \operatorname{im}g.$$  Hence, $f(\operatorname{im}g)\subseteq \operatorname{im}g$.

Comment: indeed, it was so easy, i was stupid, thank you man

Answer (score 0):

Given any set $A\subset V$, 
$$
f(A):=\{f(a):a\in V\}.
$$
So, you can think about this as the image of $f$, when restricted to the set $A$, as you mentioned.

For part 1, then, 
$$
f(\ker g)=\{f(v):v\in \ker g\}.
$$
Given $w\in f(\ker g)$, we know by the above that there is a $v$ in $\ker g$ such that $w=f(v)$. So, now the question is "Is $w$ also in $\ker g$?" I.e., is $g(w)=g(f(v))=0$? You know is that $g(v)=0$. You also know that $f(g(v))=g(f(v))$.